# Marionette AppRouter Include "/" Character in Route Params

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, single-page-application

How might I go about making the above happen? For instance, if a user navigates to this URL:

```
app.com/#search/test.com/index.html
```

with this router set up in a controller to catch it:

```
var searchRouter = new Marionette.AppRouter({
  controller: searchController,
  appRoutes: {
    'search': 'init',
    'search/:term': 'search'
  }
});
```

How would the function `search` be passed `term` inclusive of the `/` and everything that follows? In my current testing, it seems that this route isn't called at all when the search term contains a `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Routes matching are sometimes tough and can be a pain to debug, I have had a lot of issues with that so far.

So I would like to suggest you something else:

Just have 1 route to cover both scenarios and route to `init` or `search` inside your listener:

```
appRoutes: {
  'search(/:term)': 'searchListener'
},

searchListener: function(term) {
  if (!term) this.init();
  else this.search(term);
}
```

This is more just to express the idea, feel free to make it better. I hope this approach solves your problem.